# How do I enable silent authentication for the jboss-cli.sh script?

Tags: authentication, redhat, jboss-cli

I am trying to silently authenticate to the jboss-cli.sh script in the KeyCloak development branch. I am not sure how to enable it while I do my tests and then disable it after I am done, which is the agreed-upon approach by our team. I tried the following:

```
$ cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
$ ./jboss-cli.sh
```

The JBOSS continues asking for my credentials to connect, but to verify some of our tests, I have to use silent authentication.  I tried:

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c
```

and then modified **client-auth.cli** and **standalone.xml** to remove any references to **keystore** in **ManagementRealm** and **ApplicationRealm**.

Executing:

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect –file=./client-auth.cli
```

after saving the mods still required me to enter a username and password.

What am I doing wrong here?  Do I have to do something different?  If so, what?